# Magento 1.7 Local to Remote server transfer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

After transferred my magento local site into remote ... i get errors as

```
"a:5:{i:0;s:45:"Unable to read response, or response is empty";i:1;s:1151:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\magento-1.7.0.2\magento\lib\Varien\Http\Client.php(61): Zend_Http_Client->request('GET')"
```

The remote site still holding the path of my local server path how to change it . Is there any default config settings .

Comment: you can edit the configuration settings in the database, `core_config_data` table. You will find the same values here that you edit on system/configuration panel on backend.

Answer (score 0):

To a large degree this would depend on exactly which files you uploaded to the remote site, the most likely suspects are probably `var/resource_config.json` or anything in `var/cache/mage--*`. I believe you should be able to delete both, but if your a more cautious type you can always rename them.